# Verilog hdl magnitude comparator error

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have written the simple code below for a magnitude comparator. The 6 bits of C give the values of A=B,A!=B,etc; However, i am getting the following error when i run the code. How can i fix the error?

```
c2q39.v:7: error: C['sd5] is not a valid l-value in testbench.m.
c2q39.v:3:      : C['sd5] is declared here as wire.
```

My code is

```
module mag(A,B,C);
input [3:0] A,B;
output [5:0] C;

always @ (A or B)

assign C[5]=(A==B);
assign C[4]=(A!=B);
assign C[3]=(A>B);
assign C[2]=(A<B);
assign C[1]=(A>=B);
assign C[0]=(A<=B);
endmodule

module testbench;
reg [3:0] A,B;
wire [5:0] C;
mag m(A,B,C);

initial
begin
A=4'b0000;B=4'b0000;
#10 A=4'b1000;
#10 B=4'b1001;
#10 A=4'b1000;
end

initial
$monitor("%0d %b %b %b",$time,A,B,C);

endmodule
```

Comment: You have mixed the procedural block(`always`) and continuous assignment(`assign`) statements. The LHS of procedural block statement is always a `reg`. So, either declare `C` as `reg` and add `begin..end` in always block, along with removal of assign statement; or simply remove `always` block with rest of the stuff as it is.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to use assign statement in **always** block ( for more details refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641184/verilog-can-you-put-assign-statements-within-always-or-begin-end-statements) ). So you can define your output **C** as reg and implement the following way:

```
module mag(A,B,C);
input [3:0] A,B;
output reg [5:0] C;

always @ (A or B)
begin
 C[5]=(A==B);
 C[4]=(A!=B);
 C[3]=(A>B);
 C[2]=(A<B);
 C[1]=(A>=B);
 C[0]=(A<=B);
end
endmodule
```

The other way to implement is just use assign statements.

```
module mag(A,B,C);
input [3:0] A,B;
output [5:0] C;

//always @ (A or B)

assign C[5]=(A==B);
assign C[4]=(A!=B);
assign C[3]=(A>B);
assign C[2]=(A<B);
assign C[1]=(A>=B);
assign C[0]=(A<=B);

endmodule
```