# Index register with different widths

Tags: indexing, verilog, variable-assignment, assign

Is there a way to index a multibit register with the same offset but variable width? I want to do this:

```
module foo (input [1:0] data_bits);
always @ (posedge clk) begin
case (data_bits)
    2'b11:
        assign wire_data_out = {3(1'b0), data_received[7:3]};
    2'b10:
        assign wire_data_out = {2(1'b0), data_received[7:2]};
    2'b01:
        assign wire_data_out = {(1'b0), data_received[7:1]};
    2'b00:
        assign wire_data_out = data_received;
endcase
end
```

Searching for an answer I found Indexed Part Select operator "+: or -:", but it requires fixed width, which doesn't fit my needs. Is there a simpler way to write the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
always @ (posedge clk)
   wire_data_out <= data_received>>data_bits;
```

By the way:

1. you can't use assigns inside an always block.
2. In a clocked section you should use non-blocking assignments.

---

It is a single line as you requested. But I would not write my code that way. It requires that the reader is aware that Verilog will add zero bits to the top and lose the bottom bits. I would use the code as you have written (but then without the syntax errors :-):

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   case (data_bits)
   2'b00: wire_data_out <=       data_received;
   2'b01: wire_data_out <= {1'b0,data_received[7:1]};
   2'b10: wire_data_out <= {2'b0,data_received[7:2]};
   2'b11: wire_data_out <= {3'b0,data_received[7:3]};
   endcase
```

The end result will be exactly the same logic but the readability is better.

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted but I don't have enough reputation.

The blocking assigment was bad habit :(

About the assign inside always block, I checked here before using and found it was possible. Maybe you could contribute to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641184/verilog-can-you-put-assign-statements-within-always-or-begin-end-statements

Also, do you think adding a comment line to explain that Verilog add zero bits when shifting is an easier/more elegant solution?

Comment: 1/ Coding style is personal. Do what you like best. 2/ Assign uses `=` and you must use `<=` so you can't use it. The link is for non-clocked always. 3/ Procedural Continuous Assignment are not synthesisable and have a different behavior then what you think. They are deprecated: just don't use them!